# how can I add a confirmation page before deleting the data using javascript?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have an element, which redirects to another page on click like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="location.href='?page=del$id=12345'">
```

Actually, how to add some confirmation (like yes/no) before deleting that data (reloading the page)?

I have tried to write code like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" location.href="?page=del$id=12345">
```

but this code has not worked for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `button` to do this

Comment: You should not use a GET request to delete data. GET requests should be idempotent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your confirmation inline. Like this:

```
var c = confirm('Are you sure ?'); c== true ? (location.href='https://stackoverflow.com/') : ''
```

Try this one:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="var c = confirm('Are you sure ?'); c== true ? (location.href='https://stackoverflow.com/') : ''">click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add page url in href attribute code simple like this

```
<a href="?page=del$id=12345" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure ?')">Click</a>
```

Comment: thank you sir, but i want to hide a link when mouse over too. so i put "javascript:void(0);"

Comment: if you want to hide use some css class like visibility:hidden; cursor:none; something but i don't get you what exactly you want

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```js
var confirmed = false;

del.onclick = () => {
  if (confirmed) {
    location.href = del.dataset.goto;
  } else {
    del.innerText = 'Please, click again to confirm';
    confirmed = true;
  }
}
```

```css
#del {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="del" data-goto="https://stackoverflow.com">Delete</div>
```

If you prefer, you can use `<button type="button">` instead of `<div>`.

Anyway, I recommend you to separate JavaScript from HTML code.